# Java Setters via CSV file

Tags: java, getter-setter, opencsv

I have a class file with setter and getters

```
private double Amount;
private Date abcDate;

public double getAmount() {
    return Amount;
}
public void setAmount(double amount) {
    Amount = amount;
}
public Date getAbcDate() {
    return abcDate;
}
public void setAbcDate(Date abcDate) {
    this.abcDate = abcDate;
}
```

I have a CSV file with

```
Amount, 1000
abcDate, 12/03/2018
PersonName, John
PersonLocation, Berlin
```

I would like to read the CSV file and instantiate the variable via setters. I can read the CSV file using   CSVReader, Univocity, openCSV etc.

***How do I compare it to the setter class and set the value?***

Comment: Reflection would obviously work--although I'd hesitate to call this a CSV file in the traditional sense; they're normally row-oriented, while you have a sort-of hybrid.

Comment: Could you describe what exactly have and what do you want to achieve? For now, it looks that you want to create object and set correct parsed values...

Comment: @nazar_art, object is already exists. Its only setting the value of the object. What I found tricky was the matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is just with matching you can solve it like the following with the [common-csv liberary](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv):

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String amount = record.get("Amount");
    String abcDate = record.get("abcDate");

    MyDto dto = new MyDto() // use your class name here
    dto.setAmount(amount);
    dto.setAbcDate(abcDate);
    // continue to process object -> store to collection, etc
}
```